# How to transfer my IOS project from bitbucket repository to github repository?

Tags: github, repository, transfer

I am trying to transfer my project to GitHub but it didn't work.
I tried the import tool but it did not work, also I tried the following
git clone --bare https://bitbucket.org/myrepo
cd
git push --mirror https://github.com/mynewrepo
but it did not work it shows that I have large files in my project

**Error below :**

> remote: error: Trace: 9db6c476af7272b6f5454c0e76028c1a5fa9b41099cdead
> remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information. remote:
> error: File objects/pack/pack-13967a46a945c85433759d2cb64b301e3.pack
> is 411.76 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
> remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git
> Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.

*Any suggestions guys?*

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you initialise a github project in an empty directory and then just copy all the files from your bitbucket source folder to the newly created github folder? Following which you just need to make a simple git push.

Comment: I did that using :
1- git clone --bare https://bitbucket.org/myrepo
2-  push --mirror https://github.com/mynewrepo 
but this solution did not work, it shows that  "Large files detected."

Comment: The huge files might be present because of your git file history from gitbucket, this command might help you out:
git filter-repo --path example/path/to/something